# How can I run a concurrent queue of tasks using Rx?

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, rx-java2

I've found a lot of examples about it and doesn't know what's the 'right' implementation right there.

Basically I've got a object (let's call it `NBAManager`) and there's a method `public Completable generateGame()` for this object. The idea is that `generateGame` method gets called a lot of times and I want to generate games in a sequential way: I was thinking about concurrent queue. I came up with the following design: I'd create a singleton instance of `NBAService: service` for `NBAManager` and the body of `generateGame()` will look like this:

`public Completable generateGame(RequestInfo info)
    return service.generateGame(info);`

So basically I'll pass up that Completable result. And inside of that `NBAService` object I'll have a queue (*a concurrent one, because I want to have an opportunity to `poll()` and `add(request)` if there's a call of `generateGame()` while `NBAManager` was processing one of the earlier requests*) of requests. I got stuck with this:

- What's the right way to write such a job queue in Rx way? There're so many examples of it. Could you send me a link of a good implementation?
- How do I handle the logic of queue execution? I believe we've to execute if there's one job only and if there're many then we just have to add it and that's it. How can I control it without *runnable*? I was thinking about using *subjects*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to implement this, you can choose how much RxJava should be invoked. The least involvement can use a single threaded `ExecutorService` as the "queue" and `CompletableSubject` for the delayed completion:

```
class NBAService {
    static ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

    public static Completable generateGame(RequestInfo info) {
        CompletableSubject result = CompletableSubject.create();
        exec.submit(() -> {
            // do something with the RequestInfo instance
            f(info).subscribe(result);
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

A more involved solution would be if you wanted to trigger the execution when the `Completable` is subscribed to. In this case, you can go with `create()` and `subscribeOn()`:

```
class NBAService {

    public static Completable generateGame(RequestInfo info) {
        return Completable.create(emitter -> {
            // do something with the RequestInfo instance
            emitter.setDisposable(
                f(info).subscribe(emitter::onComplete, emitter::onError)
            );
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question though: will it work if I specifically want to return the result of some Completable function in 'NBAService::generateGame'? I mean I want to be able to return Completable.onError() etc. (and I hope I'm wrong but in these cases you wrote it looks like I'll return onComplete() no matter what). Basically *do something with the RequestInfo instance* is another Completable f(RequestInfo) func. So I want to call return f(RequestInfo) and not just some Actions (void func) on RequestInfo instance.

Comment: So I'm not going to do { print("hello action") } return Completable.onComplete(),

I'm going to return the result of f(RequestInfo) instead where f returns Completable.

Comment: I don't understand. So you have yet another function to return a `Completable`?

Comment: Yes, there's another function Completable `generateAndSaveGameToDB(RequestInfo info)` that **actually** generate and save game to a database and then return `Completable` (and it might fail), so we should be able to return `Completable.onError()` from `NBAService::generateGame()`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So if I could write this way that would be really what I actually want:

`CompletableSubject result = CompletableSubject.create();
        exec.submit(() -> {
           result = generateAndSaveGameToDB(info)
        }).blockingAwait();
        return result;`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @akarnord: thanks, I got the idea. One quick questions: how does CompletableSubject result wait for the single executor to complete the future? For RxNewbie guy it looks like we can push that task to single executor and then immediately return 'empty' CompletableSubject.

Comment: Well, it turned out your 1st example doesn't execute it in a sequential way that I wanted initially. I'll try your second approach then.

Comment: That can happen, given that the original post is a bit underdefined. If `f` contains threading such as its own `subscribeOn`, nothing external to `f` will likely work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for that undefined thing. Unfortunately, I've got the same memory ` java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded ` again.

So again: basically I want to wait for `f = generateAndSaveGameToDB(info)` to complete (and still be able to receive other `generateGame() ` requests, return that result from generateAndSaveGameToDB for the first request (and then process another job (request), etc. If `generateAndSaveGameToDB` returns onError we should return onError for `public static Completable generateGame(RequestInfo info)`. Does it make sense?

Comment: What about this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ae49e7a2-3a7c-48e1-85da-d8d1bcaca7e9/how-to-implement-a-single-worker-consumer-producer-queue-using-rx?forum=rx)?

Comment: It depends on how `generateAndSaveGameToDB` is implemented. If it uses `subscribeOn`, have a single-threaded `Scheduler` run it by design or expose a `Scheduler` parameter so that `Schedulers.single()` can be handed in.